# Group a list by word length

Tags: python, list

For example, I have a list, say

```
list = ['sight', 'first', 'love', 'was', 'at', 'It']
```

I want to group this list by word length, say

```
newlist = [['sight', 'first'],['love'], ['was'], ['at', 'It']]
```

Please help me on it.
Appreciation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a temp dictionary then sort by length:

```
li=['sight', 'first', 'love', 'was', 'at', 'It']

d={}
for word in li:
    d.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word)

result=[d[n] for n in sorted(d, reverse=True)] 

print result  
# [['sight', 'first'], ['love'], ['was'], ['at', 'It']]
```

You can use defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
for word in li:
    d[len(word)].append(word)

result=[d[n] for n in sorted(d, reverse=True)] 
print result
```

or use `__missing__` like so:

```
class Dicto(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key]=[]
        return self[key]

d=Dicto()
for word in li:
    d[len(word)].append(word)

result=[d[n] for n in sorted(d, reverse=True)] 
print result
```

Comment: You guys are absolutely warm heart! Since Canopy can't do groupby solution (I dont know why), I will take this solution!

Answer (score 11):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lis = ['sight', 'first', 'love', 'was', 'at', 'It']
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(lis, key=len)]
[['sight', 'first'], ['love'], ['was'], ['at', 'It']]
```

Note that for `itertools.groupby` to work properly all the items must be sorted by length, otherwise use `collections.defaultdict`(`O(N)`) or sort the list first and then use `itertools.groupby`(`O(NlogN)`). :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> lis = ['sight', 'first', 'foo', 'love', 'at', 'was', 'at', 'It']
>>> for x in lis:
...     d[len(x)].append(x)
...     
>>> d.values()
[['at', 'at', 'It'], ['foo', 'was'], ['love'], ['sight', 'first']]
```

If you want the final output list to be sorted too then better sort the list items by length and apply `itertools.groupby` to it.

Comment: [Insert standard disclaimer about sorting and `groupby` contiguity..]

Answer (score 2):

Since the `groupby` solution was already taken ;-)

```
from collections import defaultdict
lt = ['sight', 'first', 'love', 'was', 'at', 'It']                       
d = defaultdict(list)
for x in lt:
  d[len(x)].append(x)
d.values()
[['at', 'It'], ['was'], ['love'], ['sight', 'first']]
```

Comment: beat ya by 5 secs ;-)

Comment: @drewk, :-) :-), a minor nitpick though, my solution uses a `defaultdict` so it varies every so slightly from yours